# Questions on calculating probabilities from user choice data for GLM training when two objects are equivalent

Tags: probability, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, data-transformation, dataset

I’ve designed a GLM to predict user preference when presented with a choice between two buttons. However, there is some disagreement about how I’m providing collected user data to the model, and I wanted to get a third party opinion.

Below is an explanation of my logic with a simplified model:

```
Model: P ~ Button1Size + Button2Size
```

Where P is a percentage from 0-1 and button sizes can range from 1-50.

In each trial, users select between two buttons whose size can vary. The goal of the model is to predict the probability of one button of the two being chosen, given both of their sizes. For whichever button’s data is “plugged into” Button1Size, P should represent the probability it is chosen, and the model should generate (1 – that probability) if the order is reversed. An example datapoint I provide the model with is:

```
0.25 ~ 5 + 3
```

This notation indicates that, for the case where one button’s size was 5 and the other’s was 3, the button of size 5 was chosen 25% of the time (5 out of 20 users). However, because I don’t want the model to think Button2Size is somehow different, I also provide the equivalent:

```
0.75 ~ 3 + 5
```

What is in dispute are the cases where the buttons’ sizes are the same. Since I initially generated the percentage by counting how many users preferred one specific GUI button object and dividing it by the total number of users, we have a “raw” datapoint like this:

```
0.25 ~ 5 + 5
```

I believe this datapoint (and all where the sizes are the same) should be adjusted to 0.5 ~ 5 + 5. My rationale is that, for this trial among 20 users, the total number of cases where a button’s size was 5 and the other’s was 5 was 40 (two buttons per user), and the total number of times a button was chosen out of those 40 cases was 20.

The disagreeing party believes that we should not adjust this raw data count in this way, and instead ONLY provide 0.25 ~ 5 + 5 to the model. I argue that this data is measuring a different event than the datapoints where sizes are different, and that if we train the model in this way, it will give coefficients that give different percentages depending on which order we plug the buttons into the model. They replied that that might be the case, and if so, we might need to re-evaluate our approach to the experiment.

Am I correct? For this model, for all cases where the buttons are the same size X, is the probability of choosing a button of size X, given the other button is also size X, always 50%? And does this extend to models with more parameters, if the parameters pairs are also equal – e.g.,

```
P ~ Button1Size + Button2Size + Button1Length + Button2Length + …?
```